# Adding multiple localstorage on click events with jQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick, local-storage

I have a simple jQuery click event that hides a `div` if a button is clicked and hides it if the page is loaded again with `localStorage`, as below:

```
$(function () {
    var storagePrivacy = 'privacyCheck';

    if(!localStorage.getItem(storagePrivacy)) {
        $("#privacy-warning").show();
        $("body.home").addClass("privacy-header");
    }
    $(document).on('click', '#privacy-close', function() {
        localStorage.setItem(storagePrivacy, true);
        $('#privacy-warning').hide();
        $("body.home").removeClass("privacy-header");
    });
});
```

Now I need to add another event to another `div`. I tried just adding another `var` and doubling the code, as below:

```
$(function () {
    var storagePrivacy = 'privacyCheck';
    var storageUpdate = 'updateCheck';

    if(!localStorage.getItem(storagePrivacy)) {
        $("#privacy-warning").show();
        $("body.home").addClass("privacy-header");
    }
    $(document).on('click', '#privacy-close', function() {
        localStorage.setItem(storagePrivacy, true);
        $('#privacy-warning').hide();
        $("body.home").removeClass("privacy-header");
    });

    if(!localStorage.getItem(storageUpdate)) {
        $("#update-alert").show();
    }
    $(document).on('click', '#update-button', function() {
        localStorage.setItem(storageUpdate, true);
        $('#update-alert').hide();
    });
});
```

The click event works, but the browser does not save or retrieve the value for the second function. It's been a while since I've last done anything with jQuery and any help is most helpful. Thanks!

Comment: try plugging in console.log(localStorage.getItem(storageUpdate)) and see what it displays.

Comment: Both variables on console show 'null' before click and 'true' after click.

Comment: In chrome devtools, you can see the value of localStorage (among other things like cookies and session storage). Try seeing what happens before you click, after you click, and after the page has restarted.

Answer (score -1):

```
var storagePrivacy = 'privacyCheck';
var storageUpdate = 'updateCheck';
```

hey what are those for ? try to remove it, maybe the function confused because of these variable

Comment: What? These variables are just indicating the name of the key for localStorage. Removing them would do nothing.

Comment: Ah sorry mate, i understand now. I think there is nothing wrong with your code, i try it and it just works, have you solved it yet ? try to console.log & see on the localstorage on the browser console/application/local storage